# read semicolon separated strings from a file

Tags: c, string, file

How to read ";" separated strings from a file in c?
I am using the following approach:

```
char c;
c=fgetc(fp);
while(c!=EOF)
{
    int k=0;
    if(c=='\n')
    c=fgetc(fp);
    while(c!=';')
    {
        str1[k]=c;
        k++;
        c=fgetc(fp);
    }
    str1[k]='\0';
    c=fgetc(fp);
    k=0;
    while(c!=EOF && c!='\n')
    {
        str2[k]=c;
        k++;
        c=fgetc(fp);
    }
    str2[k]='\0';
    Seq(str1,str2);
    printf("\n");
    if(c==EOF)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    c=fgetc(fp);
}
```

> Input file:
>
> ```
>      Hello;world
>
>      Male;Female
>
>      where;who
> ```

I have to read different values of strings and then pass them to a function as Seq(hello,world)..and so on

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Define "better"? Fewer lines of code? More efficient? More readable? If your solution works, why fix it?

Comment: @ams More maintainable? "why fix it?" -- The OP wants to do things well ... why be discouraging?

Comment: I'd also point out that that is some of the most gdawful code ever written (including undefined behavior), so the OP should be strongly encouraged to rewrite it to call library functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (fscanf(fp, " %[^;];%s", str1, str2) == 2)
  Seq(str1, str2);
```

Just make very sure that `str1` and `str2` are large enough!

The format explained:

- (space) : skip any white-space, including line breaks.
- `%[^;]` : read a string that must not contain a semi-colon. This does not skip leading white-space, hence we had to do it explicitly (thanks @MOHAMED).
- `;` : read and discard the semi-colon. If it isn't there then matching fails.
- `%s` : read a string up until white-space, so basically until the end of the line.

`fscanf` returns the number of match fields. We're looking for two, so if the result is any other number then the input failed. If your file is well formed then `feof(fd)` should return true, otherwise the matching failed early.

To be properly paranoid, you should also include the field width of `str1` and `str2` to ensure you don't get buffer overruns. So if you allocated 100 bytes you would use `%99[^;]` (leaving one byte for a zero-terminator).

Comment: add space at the beginning of your specifier format to avoid the newline problems `" %[^;];%s"`

Comment: and if the second string contains a space then the %s will not catch the whole string then you have to change your format specifier to `" %[^;] ; %[^\n]"`

Comment: True, although the space before the `;` is superfluous. Also beware CRLF line endings, so maybe you'd want this: `" %[^;]; %[^\r\n]"`

Comment: yes this will work too

Answer (score 5):

A better approach is to read lines from the file and then use `strchr`, `strpbrk`, `strcspn`, `strtok`, `sscanf`, or other library functions to find the ';'s.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Seems alot easier to just read in the contents at once and then use functions like `strtok`, etc for parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use   **" %[^;] ; %[^\n]"**  as format specifier for fscanf() to do that.It will read the file till it encounters a semi-colon,then the semi-colon in the format specifier string would "eat away" the semi-colon after that word in the file.

Comment: I believe the `s` is an error.

Comment: yes the s is an error here

Comment: @MOHAMED Which is the correction then?Plz tell before I delete it or edit it.

Comment: Use the following format `" %[^;] ; %[^\n]"`

Comment: @ams Please correct it.I know it means "read till you encounter a ;".Where is the read stuff stored then if not in s?

Comment: @MOHAMED The values read will be stored in the locations passed as parameters?

Comment: @MOHAMED And if yes, will they be stored as strings?

Comment: `fscanf(fp, " %[^;] ; %[^\n]", str1, str2)` will store both string in str1 and in str2

Comment: @MOHAMED I badly want you to confirm this.I had read this in a book,which is not that reliable.Is this statement TOTALLY wrong-- scanf("%[^\n]s",name) ?The author (Kanetkar) says this can be used to make scanf() accept multi-word strings.Is that right or we should write it as scanf("%[^\n]",name)? should we remove the "s"?

Comment: @SheerFish you could ask new question concerning that point. I could not confirm that s is wrong in general but for this case is wrong

Comment: @MOHAMED But even if I use "s" then its compiling without error.How?

Comment: as a syntax there is no error with your format specifier. but as result execution there is problem with it

Comment: @MOHAMED In case we use a "s", will the program expect us to enter "s" and then ignore it and not store it in any variable?

Comment: yes it's exactelly that